# How to validate foreign keys in Rails validations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

In my Rails app I have `users` who can have many `projects` which in turn can have many `invoices`.

How can I make sure that a user can only create an invoice for one of **his** projects and not for another user's projects?

```
class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :number, :date, :project_id

  validates :project_id,  :presence   => true,
                          :inclusion  => { :in => ????????? }

end
```

Thanks for any help.

---

```
class InvoicesController < ApplicationController

  def new  
    @invoice = current_user.invoices.build(:project_id => params[:project_id])
  end

  def create
    @invoice = current_user.invoices.build(params[:invoice])    
    if @invoice.save
      flash[:success] = "Invoice saved."
      redirect_to edit_invoice_path(@invoice)
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

end
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that shouldn't be on a validation. You should ensure the project the user selected is one his projects.

You could do something on your controller like:

```
project = current_user.projects.find params[:project_id]
@invoice = Invoice.new(project: project)
# ...
```

Your create action could look something like this.

```
  def create
    @invoice = current_user.invoices.build(params[:invoice])
    @invoice.project = current_user.projects.find params[:invoice][:project_id]
    if @invoice.save
      flash[:success] = "Invoice saved."
      redirect_to edit_invoice_path(@invoice)
    else
      render :new
    end
  end
```

Comment: But it's quite easy to hack then! I just hacked my own application by opening my browser console, then replacing `<option value="1">My Project</option>` with `<option value="99">My Project</option>` and then submitting the form. How can I validate against that?

Comment: `current_user.projects` scopes the projects with only user's projects. When you do find on that, if it's not a user's project it will return nil. So I can't see how you hacked it.

Answer (score 1):

`project_id` is "sensitive" attribute - so remove it from attr_accessible. You are right that you should not believe params from the form and you must check it.

```
def create
  @invoice = current_user.invoices.build(params[:invoice])
  # @invoice.project_id is nil now because this attr not in attr_accessible list
  @invoice.project_id = params[:invoice][:project_id] if current_user.project_ids.include?(params[:invoice][:project_id])
  if @invoice.save
    flash[:success] = "Invoice saved."
    redirect_to edit_invoice_path(@invoice)
  else
    render :new
  end
end
```

If user tries to hack your app and change `project_id` to not owned value then method `create` render partial `new` with invalid `@invoice`. **Do not forget to leave the validation of `project_id` on presence**.

If you get exception `Can't mass-assign protected attributes...` there are several ways what to do. The simplest ways are:
1. remove line from environment configs (development, test, production)

```
# Raise exception on mass assignment protection for Active Record models
config.active_record.mass_assignment_sanitizer = :strict
```

2. Reject sensitive parameters from params before assigning.

```
# changes in method create
def create
  project_id = params[:invoice].delete(:project_id)
  @invoice = current_user.invoices.build(params[:invoice])
  @invoice.project_id = project_id if current_user.project_ids.include?(project_id)
  ...
end
```

Comment: OK, thanks! I think I am getting closer to it now. But what would my form have to look like? Right now I have `<%= f.select(:project_id, current_user.project_names %>`. But I am getting an error `Can't mass-assign protected attributes: project_id` now.

Comment: Hello. Thanks for taking the time to update your answer. I tried really hard to implement your changes but I failed. When I remove `attr_accessible` from the model, the entire record can't be saved anymore. I also wonder why the validation should be performed by the controller and not the model (where it usually happens). Luckily I managed to come up with a solution of my own and posted it above. Maybe you can have a look and tell me if it's any good or if I should give your approach a second try. Many thanks!!

Comment: I think we misunderstand each other in some details. 1. you should not remove `attr_accessible` from the model - just remove `project_id` from it. 2. I suggest to check correct project_id (belonging to current_user) in controller because usually you can not get to `current_user` from the model. I think in model should be validation only on presence of project_id. 3. I review own answer and notice that I missed `delete` in the code - please take it into consideration

Comment: OK. You are right, I think. Getting to the `current_user` from the `Invoice` model is bad code smell. I am doing it with my approach but I feel bad about it. So I like your idea of handling it in the controller. But I still can't get your code to work. If I *delete* the `project_id` (as you are suggesting), then it's no longer there and I get an error `Project can't be blank` when sending the form.

Comment: we delete `project_id` from the params to avoid problem with mass-assignment. But next line after building new `@invoice` we setup `project_id` manually (of course if if-condition returns true)

Comment: Hmm strange, the `project_id` won't get saved anyway. It's empty in the database.

Comment: try to check if-condition `if current_user.project_ids.include?(project_id)`. Maybe project_id is string when `current_user.project_ids` is array of integers. Or just remove this condition at all for testing period

Comment: Ah yes, I changed it to `project_id = params[:invoice].delete(:project_id).to_i`. The `project_id` gets saved to the database now. But invalid project_ids (from other `users`) get saved equally. There's no barrier at all.

Answer (score 0):

OK, luckily I managed to come up with a solution of my own this time.

I didn't make any changes to my controller (*"let's keep 'em skinny"*), but added a validation method to my model instead:

```
class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :number, :date, :project_id

  validates :project_id,  :presence     => true,
                          :numericality => { :only_integer => true },
                          :inclusion    => { :in => proc { |record| record.available_project_ids } }

  def available_project_ids
    user.project_ids
  end

end
```

I am not sure if this is good or bad coding practice. Maybe someone can shed some light on this. But for the moment it seems pretty safe to me and I haven't been able to hack it in any way so far.

Comment: I think it can work correctly but be careful with `user.project_ids`! The following code raise exception (I think) `pr = Project.new; pr.valid?`. It should happen because `user` is nil now and `nil.project_ids` raises an exception.